# ema-hungarian-algorithm not running

Tags: java, hungarian-algorithm

I wanted to checkout this application [hungarian system](https://code.google.com/p/ema-hungarian-algorithm/) I have imported this project in NetBeans but it is giving me error as

```
error: cannot find symbol
public class HungarianApp extends SingleFrameApplication {
  symbol: class SingleFrameApplication
```

I tried searching on same site for the file but it I was unable to find it out.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your project and rebuild it! If the NetBeans is still not found this class, please check your project dependencies.

The whole class name of SingleFrameApplication is org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication.